# how to access protected array values ?

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-5.1, protected

Hi I have this array and I am not sure how will I fetch the name , brand, image, token values from it?

```
Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartCollection Object
(
  [items:protected] => Array
     (
          [1264477c2182cc04a63fde1186741fa7] =>       Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartRowCollection Object
            (
                [associatedModel:protected] => 
                [associatedModelNamespace:protected] => 
                [items:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [rowid] => 1264477c2182cc04a63fde1186741fa7
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => washington apples
                        [qty] => 1
                        [price] => 90
                        [options] => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartRowOptionsCollection Object
                            (
                                [items:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [brand] => awesome apple
                                        [image] => C:\xampp\htdocs\srsgrocery\storage/app/products/1/apple-06.jpg
                                        [token] => WiQgUjqgHEB3HZ2ImJ6iPQWHnm246twFD3Uyk6AH
                                    )

                            )

                        [subtotal] => 90
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I am using the php framework called laravel.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save the object in a variable and do a `foreach` loop,

```
foreach($cart as $item) {
    echo $item->name;
    echo $item->options->brand;
}
```

if that's not working, you can use the `fetch` method from the `collection` class.

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_fetch

```
$item->fetch('name');
```

and the package you're using has a alternate method `search`

```
$item->search('name');
$item->search(['options' => 'name'])
```

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/src/Gloudemans/Shoppingcart/CartRowOptionsCollection.php