# How to read and convert a protected object to an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I am working with an api which answers the requests with "protected" data object

like this

```html
(
    [id:protected] => id:NYhXwGRVDzAAAAAAAAAA62
    [name:protected] => 5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
    [rev:protected] => 014a0000000150eaacf0
    [size:protected] => 25136208
    [server_modified:protected] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
    [has_explicit_shared_members:protected] => 
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => 5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
            [path_lower] => /5cf8cdd54328c.edf
            [path_display] => /5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
            [id] => id:NYhXwGRVDzAAAAAAAA125
            [client_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
            [server_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
            [rev] => 014a0000000150eaacf0
            [size] => 25136208
            [is_downloadable] => 1
            [content_hash] => 86442139304784e3b18d1d46f1b20bc48847
        )
)
```

I have converted the object to array with the following code

```
$metadata = (array)$file->getMetadata();
```

```html
Array
(
    [*id] => id:NYhXwGRVDzAAAAAA44554
    [*name] => 5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
    [*rev] => 014a0000000150eaacf0
    [*size] => 25136208
    [*media_info] => 
    [*sharing_info] => 
    [*path_display] => /5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
    [*client_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
    [*server_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z

    [*data] => Array
        (
            [name] => 5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
            [path_display] => /5cf8cdd54328c.EDF
            [id] => id:NYhXwGRVDzAAAAAAA23382
            [client_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
            [server_modified] => 2019-06-06T08:25:00Z
            [rev] => 014a0000000150eaacf0
            [size] => 25136208
            [is_downloadable] => 1
            [content_hash] => 86442139304784e3b18d1d46f1b20bc4884
        )

)
```

But when i try to print the value `print_r($metadata['*size']);`

> Notice: Undefined index: *size in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\kardion\kardion\sistema\download.php on line 28

I think it will be a very easy answer but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378536/5284695

Comment: What API is this? I'd normally expect there to be a getter method available.

Comment: _“like this”_ - what is the _actual_ type of that API response? This is probably some sort of object instance, and as such it should provide getter methods to get at those protected properties. Do a `var_dump($file->getMetadata());`, and show us the output of that, that should reveal what this actually is.

Comment: @Jonnix is Dropbox Api V2

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: @Jonnic kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk

Comment: And what type is the object you've dumped out?

Comment: Looking at the SDK code, you might be able to use `$obj->getData()` to get the data array, or `$obj->getDataProperty('size')` to just get the size. See https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/blob/f8ab4d32fb832ea18a20ac8fbba76f675e7a6fff/src/Dropbox/Models/BaseModel.php

Comment: `var_dump($metadata);`   return  object(Kunnu\Dropbox\Models\FileMetadata)#31 (12)

Comment: Yep, that class extends BaseModel, so my above comment should work

Comment: My English is very bad . some times I can not understand all the documentation.

I have solved the problem

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure where all those asterisks are coming from. I can't see them documented in any of the PHP `::getMetadata` functions. Is this something you wrote yourself? I would suggest trying to remove any `*`s before attempting to read the index, and I suspect that's what's causing your error. Have you tried just `print_r($metadata['size']);`?

Comment: Ty for anwer, 
`print_r($metadata['size']);`

 Notice: Undefined index: size in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\kardion\kardion\sistema\download.php on line 28